# PHP Dynamic Table Data Results Vertically not Horizontally

Tags: php, dynamic, html-table

I have an array of data I wish to be displayed in a dynamic table but need it vertically.

At present I'm getting the following output:

Example 1:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4
5 - 6 - 7 - 8
9 - ... etc.
```

But I need it like so:

Example 2:

```
1 - 4 - 7
2 - 5 - 8
3 - 6 - 9
```

I've searched Google and on stack but can't find a straight forward answer that I can use to solve my problem.

```
$array = array("4|Four","12|Twelve","2|Two","5|Five","11|Eleven","3|Three","1|One","6|Six","10|Ten","8|Eight","7|Seven","9|Nine");

$maxcols = 3;
$i = 0;

$table = "<table width=\"80%\" border=\"0\">\n";
$table .= "<tr>\n";


if(!empty($array))
{
rsort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);
for($p=0;$p<sizeof($array);$p++)
{
list($num,$title) = explode("|", trim($array[$p]));


if ($i == $maxcols) 
{
$i = 0;
$table .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
}
$table .= "<td>"."[ ".$num." ]"." ".$title."</td>\n";
$i++;
}

while ($i < $maxcols) 
{
$table .= "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
$i++;
}

$table .= "</tr>\n";
$table .= "</table>\n";
}

echo $table;
```

This code above outputs as seen in the first example but I can't get my head around to get it to output as seen in the second example.

Comment: The array index will always be integer?

Comment: @frz3993 as in the example code.. i need the numbers to run vertically as in example 2

Comment: @frz3993 i have edited the post to show an example array :)

Comment: So what if you had 10 values instead of 9 in the example of what you're going for? Would it start a new column?

Comment: @Don'tPanic hi.. ideally i want it to start a new row.. i want to choose how many columns via a variable :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought of using array_chunk to break the array into rows, but then it occurred to me it could be done just as well with only math.

```
$rows = 3; // define how many rows as you want

$array = array("4|Four","12|Twelve","2|Two","5|Five","11|Eleven","3|Three","1|One",
    "6|Six","10|Ten","8|Eight","7|Seven","9|Nine");
rsort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);

// determine number of columns needed to fit the values into the number of rows you want
$columns = count($array) / $rows; 

$table = '<table width="80%" border="0">';
for ($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) { 
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for ($j=0; $j < $columns; $j++) {
        $index = (int) ($j * $rows + $i); // Do the math to get the proper array index
        if (isset($array[$index])) {                    
            list($num,$title) = explode("|", trim($array[$index]));
            $table .= "<td>"."[ ".$num." ]"." ".$title."</td>\n";
        } else {
            $table .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}
$table .= '</table>';
```

The above example produces a grid like this, where the numbers are array keys.

```
0  3  6  9
1  4  7  10
2  5  8  11
```

The math that produces this grid with two for loops is like this:

```
0*3+0  1*3+0  2*3+0  3*3+0
0*3+1  1*3+1  2*3+1  3*3+1
0*3+2  1*3+2  2*3+2  3*3+2
```

or in words, (column index * total number of rows) + row index. The nested loop part will stay the same whether you want to specify the number of rows or the number of columns. The only thing that should need to change is the math at the beginning to calculate how many rows are needed for the specified number of columns or vice versa. If you change the beginning part to

```
$columns = 3; 
$rows = ceil(count($array) / $columns);
```

Then you should be able to specify column count rather than row count. The `ceil` is necessary because any remainder of the division must be rounded up in order to get the total number of rows needed. I think this is why you were getting the duplicate values when you first switched rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer really appreciated the comments in the code too awesome. For my needs i swtched the rows and colmns so i could assign the colums as a variable and let the code work out the rows :) cheers again!

Comment: I thought i had it right but still not 100%.. your example for rows works but i want to do this for columns instead.. i tried swapping the code around but i get a duplicate of the last entry of each column at the start of the next.. any ideas how i can change the rows = 3 to columns = 3 instead.. sorry to be a pain thanks so much

Comment: No worries, I'll take another look at it when I get back to my computer.

Comment: thank you so much again for your help and detailed explinations.. this works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
    <table align="center" style="width:40%;">
<tr>
<th>Column 1</th>
<th>Column 2</th>
<th>Column 3</th>
</tr>
<?
$rotate = 0;
$amount = 1;
while($amount <= 50)
{
if($rotate == 0) {
echo '<tr>
<td>test</td>';
$rotate = 1;
}
else if($rotate == 1) {
echo '<td>test2</td>';
$rotate = 2;
}
else if($rotate == 2) {
echo '<td>test3</td>';
$rotate = 0;
echo '</tr>';
}

$amount++;

}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

This will work on a blank php page - so you can see how it works.

Comment: hi and thanks for trying to help. I tried implementing your code with mine but i get the same output. Here is a screenshot [link](http://s16.postimg.org/kgoym665h/example.jpg) This is what i already have but i need example 2

Comment: @John maybe I'm not understanding exactly what you are going for.

Answer (score 0):

To further expand on @DontPanic's answer the problem of translating array keys can be abstracted in such a way that you can have any number of columns. Both implementations math are basically equivalent.

```
// returns a closure that can be used to translate the index order

function getIndexTranslator($list, $numColumns) {
    $numRows = ceil(count($list)/$numColumns);
    return function($x) use ($list, $numColumns, $numRows){
        return ($x % $numColumns) * $numRows + floor($x / $numColumns);
    };
}
```

You can then use the returned function to allow you to walk the elements in the required document order.  Here is how you would use the above function.

```
$transformer = getIndexTranslator($arr, 3);

for($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++){
    echo $arr[$transformer($x)], $x % 3 == 2?"\n":" ";
}
```

Play around with it a your self [here](http://3v4l.org/p6kPq)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to post a solution - i will have a play with this also :)